# How to animate a 3d plot with python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, 3d

I currently have a 3d plot with python, but I want to animate it. Specifically, I have motion analysis data which is stored in 3 arrays (for x,y,z axes) that is around 300 frames long. I can currently plot it three-dimensionally but I want it to be able to see the actual movement as the frames go by, so I want the program to animate the path of movement, chronologically. Here is my current, non-working code, which is fairly simple:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.plot(data_x, data_y, data_z)
ax.view_init(elev = 25, azim = 80)

plt.show()
```

data_x, data_y, and data_z all store the subject's wrist's movement across 300 frames, for x,y, and z axes.

I am running python 3.6

Comment: ...plot inside a `for` loop?

Comment: Also see the matplotlib examples, e.g. this one: https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html